# Draw and position many png files in Cairo

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

My program runs a physics engine with a bunch of interacting circles, and I'm trying to draw an asteroid png image over each circle.

I understand you can make a surface from a png file from this:

```
cairo_surface_t *image = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png ("image.png");
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about scaling and drawing the png file to the right dimension? From what I understand of the API I think I might need to call cairo_image_surface_get_data (), but I don't know what to do with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will need to invest some time reading the [cairo API docs](http://cairographics.org/manual/index.html), e.g. for scaling you either use `cairo_scale` or `cairo_transform` [read on](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html)

So after you did setup your view matrix with the above functions, all you have to do is a

```
cairo_set_source_surface (cr, surface, x, y);
cairo_paint (cr);
```

(freely taken from http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/cairoimages/)